# Write google sheets script to Randomly pick from a range of cells and print in a cell

Tags: random, scripting, google-sheets

So want to write a script in google sheets that will be activated with a button. For example I have A1 says "Option 1",A2 says "Option 2", A3 says "Option 3". I want to make a button that when i press it, it will randomly pick from A1-A3 and print it in A4. So it will print one of the 3 cells Option 1, Option 2, or Option 3, into another cell into Cell A4

Comment: [Please Read How to Ask on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Put this in A4:

=index(A1:A3, randbetween(1, counta(A1:A3) ) )

Then attach this function to your button:

```
  function random() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  var val=ss.getRange("A1").getValue()
  var clr =ss.getRange("A1").clearContent()
  ss.getRange("A1").setValue(val)
}
```

The clear and set is needed to make the formula recalculate. This will get whatever value is in A1.

Comment: So what if the options change. I have validation for each cell  from a list of options that are in another sheet, that can be selected. So it won't always say the same thing. How would that change the script function?